# Unsupported API version 1.1, unless called with an OAuth header

Tags: jawbone

I am trying to use pub-sub method to subscribe to the events of a specific user. I am able to successfully authenticate the user but when I call the pub-sub url I get the following error.

```
{"meta":{"error_detail":"Unsupported API version 1.1, unless called with an OAuth header","code":404,"error_type":"endpoint_error","time":1480394928,"message":"Not Found","user_xid":""},"data":{}}
```

Code:
This code is called inside the success callback of the OAuth2.0 Authentication.

```
var subscription_url = "https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/pubsub?webhook=https://*****/pushJawbone";
$http.post(
    subscription_url, {
       headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + accessToken
       }
    }
).success(
    function(response) {
       console.log("Jawbone User Subscription Successful" + response);
    }
).error(
    function(error) {
       console.log("Jawbone sub unsucessful: " + JSON.stringify(error));
     }
)
```

Comment: This is the error response you get when your accessToken is invalid/missing. Are you able to use the same accessToken for other API calls?

Comment: Like I said above this is called inside the success callback method of OAuth 2.0. Inside the method I am using the access token that I received. So how would it be invalid? Just before this call I called a GET on User Endpoint with the same access token and it was a success.

Comment: If you manually POST to the pubsub endpoint with this accessToken, what response do you get?

Comment: Tried I get the following{
  "meta": {
    "code": 401,
    "error_detail": "You must be logged in to perform that action",
    "error_type": "authentication_error",
    "message": "Unauthorized"
  },
  "data": {}
}

Comment: And that's the same token you can successfully use to get user data? Could you email apisupport @ jawbone.com with your client id and the token, so we can debug further?

Comment: Sure Ray Thanks for the help. Will send in a support request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not Jawbone API. The problem was in the angular $http method. For some reason with the above code it is not sending the headers at all so the OAuth error.
It works fine when I use the below code.

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: subscription_url,
     headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
     }
}).success(
    function(response) {
         console.log("Jawbone User Subscription Successful" + response);

    }
).error(
    function(error) {
         console.log("Jawbone sub unsucessful: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
)
```

Thanks Ray for all the help.